# CBT_Hook, HCBT_MINMAX event, or sub-classing to keep dialog window hidden. C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling, hook, messaging

I am trying to prevent a dialog password window that MS Access opens for an encrypted accdb file from becoming visible. (Instead I enter the password using the SendMessage API through a startup program).

I tried installing a CBT_Hook, however the HCBT_MINMAX event for the dialog window does not fire in the same way as other regular windows i.e.: the low order word of lParam does not contain the expected show-window value (which I could then override). [It does work as expected for regular windows].

The window is first created as hidden so modifying the CBT_CREATEWND structure in the HCBT_CREATEWND event does not help.[I tried setting ->cx and ->cy to 0 size, but the child windows are forcing a minimum size]

I also tried sub-classing the dialog window (as soon as the HCBT_CREATEWND is fired I subclass it), but after that, setting lParam to FALSE for the WM_SHOWWINDOW message did not prevent the window from showing.

I also tried canceling (RETURN 0) most WM_ messages the window was getting , such as WM_ACTIVATE, WM_SHOWWINDOW etc. but to no avail.

Canceling the WM_NCCALCSIZE message helped, but that didn’t prevent the child windows from showing, so it does not really help.

Any ideas?

[At present, before starting Access I am enumerating all windows every 10ms and as soon as I find the password dialog box I am sending it a message to hide, but even doing that every 10 ms causes it to flash on and off once when it is discovered, I would like to prevent this.

Starting Access using window style hidden does not help as the main Access app stays hidden but not the dialog box.]

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this (and other similar scenarios to hide a dialog box created by another process on creation, is as follows):

In the CBT_Hook subclass the dialog box as soon as it is created (CBT_CREATEWND is fired).

In the window subclass function, set window to transparent the first time it is called.

```
if (done != TRUE) {
        LONG_PTR exstyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        if (!(exstyle & WS_EX_LAYERED)) {
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exstyle | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        }
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 0, LWA_ALPHA);
        done = TRUE;
    }
```

Now window will not flash on the screen.